# Trouble in running the MASM file: syntax error

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, masm, dosbox

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rOWl.png)

This is my code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    hour db 0
    minute db 0
    second db 0

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ; Take input from the user for starting time (seconds)
    mov ah, 01h ; Function to read character from keyboard
    int 21h     ; Read character from keyboard
    sub al, '0' ; Convert ASCII value to actual number
    mov second, al

    ; Take input from the user for starting time (minutes)
    mov ah, 01h ; Function to read character from keyboard
    int 21h     ; Read character from keyboard
    sub al, '0' ; Convert ASCII value to actual number
    mov minute, al

    ; Take input from the user for starting time (hours)
    mov ah, 01h ; Function to read character from keyboard
    int 21h     ; Read character from keyboard
    sub al, '0' ; Convert ASCII value to actual number
    mov hour, al

clock_loop:
    
   display_time:
        call clear_screen
        
        mov dl, hour   ; Display hours on screen 
        add dl,'0'
        mov ah,02h 
        int 21h
        
        call colon
        
        mov dl, minute   ; Display minutes on screen 
        add dl,'0'
        mov ah,02h 
        int 21h
        
         call colon
        
         mov dl ,second   ; Display seconds on screen 
         add dl,'0'
         mov ah ,02h 
         int 21h
    
        
       inc second   ;
       cmp second ,10  
       jne display_time  
       
       xor second ,second      line 61
       inc minute  
       cmp minute ,10  
       jne display_time  
       
       xor minute ,minute      line 66
       inc hour  
       cmp hour ,12
       jne display_time
       
        xor hour ,hour         line 71
        
        call clear_screen
        
        mov dl, '0'   ; Display hours on screen 
        mov ah,02h 
        int 21h
        
        call colon
        
        mov dl, '0'   ; Display minutes on screen 
        mov ah,02h 
        int 21h
        
         call colon
        
         mov dl ,'0'   ; Display seconds on screen 
         mov ah ,02h 
         int 21h
         
          jmp clock_loop

    exit:                      line 93
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h

main endp

clear_screen proc
    mov ah, 06h ; Function to clear the screen
    xor al, al  ; Attribute for blank character (space)
    xor bh, bh  ; Page number (0 for current page)
    mov cx, 0   ; Upper left corner of the screen
    mov dx, 184Fh ; Lower right corner of the screen
    int 10h     ; Call BIOS video interrupt to clear the screen
    ret
clear_screen endp

colon proc
    
     push ax
     
     push dx
     
     push bx
     
     push cx
    
    mov dl, ':'   ; Display colon on screen
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    
    
    
     pop cx
     
     pop bx
     
     pop dx
     
     pop ax
    
    ret
colon endp

end main
```

How to fix this program?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> xor second ,second 
> ...
> xor minute ,minute 
> ...
> xor hour ,hour
> ```

In x86 assembly, you can't use 2 memory references like that in this `xor` instruction (or any other instruction for that matter). Your intent is to zero the memory-based variables, so just `mov` a 0 into them:

```
mov  second ,0
...
mov  minute ,0
...
mov  hour, 0
```

---

> ```
> exit:
>   mov ax, 4C00h
>   int 21h
> ```

Isn't `exit` a reserved word for MASM, hence the error message?
Maybe you could label this "ExitToDOS:".

---

> ```
> cmp hour ,12
> jne display_time
> ```

There is nothing in your program that can deal with **2**-digit numbers. Probably best to not allow for the hours 10 and 11 (not very life-like but then again this is just an exercise, isn't it?), so write it like:

```
cmp  hour ,10
jne  display_time
```

---

> ```
> cmp hour ,12
> jne display_time
> xor hour ,hour 
> call clear_screen
> mov dl, '0'   ; Display hours on screen 
> mov ah,02h 
> int 21h
> call colon
> mov dl, '0'   ; Display minutes on screen 
> mov ah,02h 
> int 21h
> call colon
> mov dl ,'0'   ; Display seconds on screen 
> mov ah ,02h 
> int 21h
> jmp clock_loop
> ```

This part of the code where you display "0:0:0" is totally redundant. The code at the top of the loop already does this. Better write:

```
cmp  hour ,10
jne  display_time
mov  hour, 0 
jmp  display_time
```